# How to implement Rails Turbo Streams and Nested Resources via Modals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1, hotwire-rails

I'm using [Viget's Fancy Form Modals](https://www.viget.com/articles/fancy-form-modals-with-rails-turbo/) in my rails application to launch modals for my `new` and `edit` views. This works great until I run into the use case of nested resources.

I have a `courses` model which `has_many` `courselocations`. My desire is to be able to edit or create `courselocations` from my `course` edit view, here's my setup;

Courselocation Model:

```
class Courselocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course, touch: true, class_name: 'Course', :foreign_key => "course_id", optional: true

  after_update_commit {
    broadcast_replace_to "admin_courselocations", target: "admin_courselocation_#{id}", partial: "/admin/courselocations/courselocation"
    broadcast_replace_to "admin_course_sessions_list", target: "admin_courselocation_#{id}", partial: "/admin/courselocations/courselocation"
   }
end
```

Course Model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courselocations, class_name: 'Courselocation', :foreign_key => "course_id"
end
```

Routes

```
resources :courses do
  resources :courselocations
  resources :testimonials
end
```

Courselocation Controller

```
class Admin::CourselocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course
  before_action :set_courselocation, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /courselocations
  def create
    @courselocation = Courselocation.new(courselocation_params)

    @courselocation = @course.courselocations.build(courselocation_params)

    if @courselocation.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to admin_course_courselocations_path(@course), notice: "#{@courselocation.name} added."
        end
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /courselocations/1
  def update
    if @courselocation.update(courselocation_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to edit_admin_courselocation_path(@courselocation), notice: "#{@courselocation.name} was saved."
        end
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /courselocations/1
  def destroy
    @courselocation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_admin_course_path(@course), notice: 'Session Deleted.' }
      format.turbo_stream
    end

    expire_fragment('homepage_course')
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_course
      @course = Course.friendly.find(params[:course_id])
    end

    def set_courselocation
      #@courselocation = Courselocation.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @courselocation = @course.courselocations.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def courselocation_params
      params.require(:courselocation).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :country_code, :course_id)
    end
end
```

Partial containing the list of associated `courselocations` to the `course`

```
  <ul class="list row col-lg-12 course-sessions-list">
      <%= turbo_frame_tag "admin_course_sessions_list", :class => "col-lg-12 row", target: '_top' do %>
        <%= render @course.courselocations.order(created_at: :desc) %>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Courselocation Partial:

```
<li id="<%= "admin_#{dom_id(courselocation)}" %>" class="card-container card-container-fill-ghost lg-pad-base-all col-lg-4 col-lg-margin">
  <section class="col col-lg-12">
    <%= link_to edit_admin_courselocation_path(courselocation), class: 'row middle location-details-container col-lg-12', data: { "turbo-frame": "modal" } do %>
      <div class="location-details col-lg-10 col-lg-margin">
        <h3><%= courselocation.name %></h3>
        <h5><%= courselocation.city %>, <%= courselocation.state %></h5>
        <% if courselocation.address.present? %>
          <p class="small-text"><%= courselocation.address %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2">
        Manage
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </section>
</li>
```

Edit View launched via Modal:

```
<%= render "admin/shared/modal" do %>
  <div class="overlay-content-body col-lg-7 center">
    <%= form_for([:admin, @course, @courselocation], local: true, :html => {multipart: true, :id =>  "admin_#{dom_id(@courselocation)}"}) do |f| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'admin/shared/form_errors', :locals => {item: @courselocation} %>
      <section class="form-main">
        <%= render 'form', f: f %>
        <h1><%= @courselocation.course_id %></h1>
        <%= f.hidden_field :course_id %>
        <section class="form-footer">
          <%= f.submit 'Save Changes', :class => 'button button-sm button-primary lg-magin-sm-right', :data => { :disable_with => "Saving Changes" }, :id => "itemSubmit" %>
          <%= link_to 'Delete Session', admin_course_courselocation_path(@course), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'danger form-delete' %>
        </section>
      </section>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form submits fine but the turbo_stream target doesn't get replaced, instead i get the following error which seems to tell me that the `course_id` isn't being passed in the `broadcast_replace_to` but I'm not sure how to solve this?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/courselocations", :course_id=>nil, :id=>"test"}, missing required keys: [:course_id]):
    1: <li id="<%= "admin_#{dom_id(courselocation)}" %>" class="card-container card-container-fill-ghost lg-pad-base-all col-lg-4 col-lg-margin">
    2:   <section class="col col-lg-12">
    3:     <%= link_to edit_admin_course_courselocation_path(@course, courselocation), class: 'row middle location-details-container col-lg-12', data: { "turbo-frame": "modal" } do %>
    4:       <div class="location-details col-lg-10 col-lg-margin">
    5:         <h3><%= courselocation.name %></h3>
    6:         <h5><%= courselocation.city %>, <%= courselocation.state %></h5>
```

Comment: You only need to broadcast from the model if you are wanting the Course location Edits to immediately be visible to other users of your app, in which case you'd need use the `turbo_stream_from` helper. 
It seems in your situation you can just use Turbo Frames to let a user edit a course location without rendering the whole edit course location page. I think you'd need an edit method in your controller for this.

Comment: I do want to update the list of `courselocations` so a user can see any changes to existing `courselocations` or new entries reflected.

Comment: So the user editing the course location is the only person who immediately needs to see the change? If so, this is be doable with Turbo Frames. As I mentioned, if you want other users who are using the app at the same time to see the changes, then can by refreshing a page as normal or you can implement the model broadcasting with turbo streams which will show instant changes to all users without a page refresh. I'd recommend watching this for a turbo frames guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WeKlk7GG80&t=1110s

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself correctly, the issue is that i'm not sure how to pass `course_id` on update so the targeted frame is updated. Currently I get the following error `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/courselocations", :course_id=>nil, :id=>"test"}, missing required keys: [:course_id]):`

Comment: Difficult to work out what you're trying to do without seeing the source code. The error you're getting looks to be because you're redirecting to `edit_admin_courselocation_path(@courselocation)` which doesn't exist.. Have you tried redirecting to `redirect_to admin_courselocation_path(@courselocation)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to solve this, but I had the same problem trying to update partials within nested routes with turbo streams, so posting this here in case it's of any help.

I needed to add in **locals** option to the broadcasts - not just for the nested item (in your case, *courselocations*), but also for the parent (*course*). You can access these values in the broadcast by using "self",  So in your case I believe this would be changing from:

```
broadcast_replace_to "admin_courselocations", target: "admin_courselocation_#{id}", partial: "/admin/courselocations/courselocation"
```

to:

```
broadcast_replace_to "admin_courselocations", target: "admin_courselocation_#{id}", partial: "/admin/courselocations/courselocation", locals: { courselocation: self, course: self.course_id }
```

That way, when the partial is rendered there are values assigned to the local variables.

It's also recommended to use the `broadcast_replace_later_to` rather than `broadcast_replace_to` as mentioned in the source:

> As a rule, you should use the _later versions of everything except for remove when broadcasting within a real-time path, like a controller or model, since all those updates require a rendering step, which can slow down execution. You don't need to do this for remove, since only the dom id for the model is used.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using variable `@course` in the partial and when it is rendering via a turbo stream that variable doesn't exist.  You either have to update the template to use a locals hash or you could get to `@course` from your `courselocation` if possible.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/courselocations", :course_id=>nil, :id=>"test"}, missing required keys: [:course_id]):
    1: <li id="<%= "admin_#{dom_id(courselocation)}" %>" class="card-container card-container-fill-ghost lg-pad-base-all col-lg-4 col-lg-margin">
    2:   <section class="col col-lg-12">
    3:     <%= link_to edit_admin_course_courselocation_path(@course, courselocation), class: 'row middle location-details-container col-lg-12', data: { "turbo-frame": "modal" } do %>
    4:       <div class="location-details col-lg-10 col-lg-margin">
    5:         <h3><%= courselocation.name %></h3>
    6:         <h5><%= courselocation.city %>, <%= courselocation.state %></h5>
```